# Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I have tried to do training and model validation from the Pascal VOC XML dataset but an error appears that the data is not read at all with the following error

`ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0`

```
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Number of training batches: 0
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Number of validation batches: 0
```

I have tried to do image training and validation from the Pascal VOC XML dataset program code as follows:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL
import scipy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV3Small
dataset_path = "datavoc"
output_path = "output"
num_classes = 10  # Replace 10 with the actual number of classes in your dataset
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")
for folder in ["train", "test", "valid"]:
    folder_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, folder)
    output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_path, folder)
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(output_folder_path)
    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith(".xml"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, file_name.replace(".xml", ".jpg"))
            tree = ET.parse(file_path)
            root = tree.getroot()
            objects = []
            for obj in root.findall("object"):
                name = obj.find("name").text
                xmin = int(obj.find("bndbox/xmin").text)
                ymin = int(obj.find("bndbox/ymin").text)
                xmax = int(obj.find("bndbox/xmax").text)
                ymax = int(obj.find("bndbox/ymax").text)
                objects.append({"name": name, "xmin": xmin, "ymin": ymin, "xmax": xmax, "ymax": ymax})
            img_path = file_path.replace(".xml", ".jpg")
            img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
            x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
            x = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3.preprocess_input(x)
            i = 0
            for batch in datagen.flow(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0), batch_size=1):
                batch_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(batch[0])
                batch_img.save(os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"{file_name.replace('.xml', '')}_{i}.jpg"))
                i += 1
                if i == 10:
                    break
train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=os.path.join(output_path, "train"), target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32,class_mode="categorical")
print(f"Number of training batches: {len(train_data)}")
valid_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=os.path.join(output_path, "valid"), target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32,class_mode="categorical")
print(f"Number of validation batches: {len(valid_data)}")
base_model = MobileNetV3Small(include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=10, validation_data=valid_data)
```